# Firebase data retrieve with random keys

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase data structure for my android app and I want to retrieve the data from random keys generated by push() method which is child of Forum node which is a child of root of the database. Please suggest me a way to do this. Thanks.

[image: data structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the values of all the children under `Forums` node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference forumsRef = db.child("Forums");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String ques = ds.child("ques").getValue(String.class);
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String uid = ds.child("uid").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + " / " + ques + " / " + title + " / " + uid);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
};
forumsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of the children nodes of the parent "Forum" node. Just use getChildren() method. Then just randomly select one of the child node at position index.

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child("Forums");
Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = snapshot.getChildren();

for (DataSnapshot child: children) {
        Object obj = child.getValue(Object.class);
}
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the name, ques, title and UID from every child of the forum node and then store them in a recycler or list view, kind of a timeline in social networking sites like Instagram and Facebook etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Firebase has its own recyclerview implementation. Check this link: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: and you can do what you are saying by just using the code that I provided as well. You will have to work on it a bit

Answer (score 1):

first you should write your class model **"FormusModel"** to store the data from server 
you can use this

```
  >   > 

rootRef.child("Forums").addChildEventListener(new
    > ChildEventListener() {
    >     >                 @Override
    >     >                 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    >     >                     ForumsModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(FormusModel.class);
//now you can use model.getname();.... 
    >     }
```

*Note:* you must implemnt another method like **onChildCahnge** listener

Comment: I don't know the forums id, it's created by the push() method which is unique everytime, it's randomly generated key